# draft-to-html with React's dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, draftjs

I'm using `draft-to-html` npm package to display `draftjs` content to a div using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Something like this:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: draftToHtml(JSON.parse(intro)) }} />
```

`intro` is user input and have not been sanitized. This feels bad but shouldn't `draft-to-html` only output known html tags such as `H1-6, ul, ol, pre, p` etc.?

Also, how would I sanitize a draftjs object?

Answer (score 0):

You should be ok. If you look at https://github.com/jpuri/draftjs-to-html#supported-conversions it shows all the text transformations that will happen:

> Following is the list of conversions it supports:
>
> Convert block types to corresponding HTML tags:
>
> Block Type    HTML Tag
>
> 1. header-one    h1
> 2. header-two    h2
> 3. header-three  h3
> 4. header-four   h4
> 5. header-five   h5
> 6. header-six    h6
> 7. unordered-list-item   ul
> 8. ordered-list-item ol
> 9. blockquote    blockquote
> 10. code pre
> 11. unstyled p
>
>     It performs these additional changes to text of blocks:
>
>     replace blank space in beginning and end of block with  
>       replace \n with 
>       replace < with <
>       replace > with >